# Does Cholestyramine (CSM) raise Tyramine levels?

Tags: biochemistry, medicine, medicinal-chemistry

This is a layman's question.

Will ingesting Cholestyramine (CSM, the resin, in powdered form to be specific) raise tyramine levels?

I am asking because Cholestyramine clearly has "tyramine" in its name, so i don't understand the chemistry behind all this and/or how this interacts with the body.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why "tyramine" is in the name "cholestyramine", but the molecular structure of tyramine is not present as part of the molecular structure of cholestyramine. Specifically, in tyramine the amino group is on the beta-carbon from the ring, and in cholestyramine the ammonium group is on the alpha-carbon (note the different number of points between the ring and the nitrogen in the line structures provided). I find it highly doubtful any reasonable metabolic reactions by the body could generate tyramine from cholestyramine.

[Cholestyramine molecular structure](https://images.app.goo.gl/WS7K3f2mRqX7k7jR9)

[Tyramine molecular structure](https://images.app.goo.gl/jnaR3GojeysjVGsU7)